# Can git diff cycle through changed files via command line?

Tags: git, diff

Like everyone I often have multiple files with changes and it would be nice to be able to call a command that will diff each file individually and cycle through the changes, is that possible or will I need to write a script for this?

Thank you

Edit: For clarification the type of flow I'm looking for is I do "git diff *cycle-files*" and it brings up the first file with changes, I look over those changes then I hit N or something and it takes me to the next file, rinse repeat until I've looked at all files with changes individually.

Comment: Do you want something that works at the command line?  `git difftool` does exactly this with your graphical difftool of choice.

Comment: Maybe I should just start using a gui for this, I tend to do everything in command line with git so I have all my attention in one place, good recommendation

Comment: I just run `git diff` or `git diff --cached`, which pipes output through `less`.  Then in `less` I type: `/^diff --git` (or some slight variation, depending on mood etc :-) ) to find each change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU xargs at your disposal you can:

```
git diff --name-only | xargs -I{} sh -c 'git diff {} | less'
```

to pipe the individual diffs into less.

Comment: Use this variant if you're having trouble getting the output in color (tested using Cygwin): `git diff --name-only | xargs -I{} sh -c 'git diff --color=always {} | less --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS'`.

Answer (score 2):

To cycle through each changed file with diffed blocks, selecting which parts to include in the next commit, use:

`git add -p .`

That is "partial add".  If you answer "no" to each block, it is equivalent to the `git diff` you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful! This should be marked as the correct answer. EDIT: okay, I have to correct my answer - this makes it possible to stage individual changes within files, not one file with many changes in one go. However, exactly the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Use `git add -p path_to/filename` for an individual file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by cycle through, but `git diff` will show every changed file (in the specified folder):

```
[timwolla@/tmp/test master]git diff
diff --git a/a b/a
index f70f10e..0653421 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 A
+a
diff --git a/b b/b
index 223b783..167f258 100644
--- a/b
+++ b/b
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 B
+b
```

If you really need to call a command on every file you can use `git diff --numstat` in combination with `awk` to get a list of changed files:

```
[timwolla@/tmp/test master]git diff --numstat |awk '{print $3}'
a
b
```

If you pipe that output through `xargs` you can call the command on every file:

```
[timwolla@/tmp/test master]git diff --numstat |awk '{print $3}' |xargs cat
A
a
B
b
```

Comment: I added a edit which I'll paste to you:
For clarification the type of flow I'm looking for is I do "git diff *cycle-files*" and it brings up the first file with changes, I look over those changes then I hit N or something and it takes me to the next file, rinse repeat until I've looked at all files with changes individually.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want.  The 3 way output is pretty ugly. You'll need `diff3` from [diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/).
Then put the following in a script named `dif` (I use `zsh` you may use something else).

```
#!/bin/sh 

diff3 $1 $BASE $2
```

Then run this with `git difftool -x ./dif`.  This will run `diff3` on each changed file which spits out a change summary.  You'll then have the option to step to the next file.  You can tweak the `diff3` parameters but I haven't found anything that looks nice.

We can get a much nicer two column diff similar to what you see in a graphical diff tool with this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

diff -y --suppress-common-lines $1 $2 | less
```